# Showing array on view in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, web-services

I have to show a JSON array values on a table I made with Angular JS. When I load the page calls the web service and get a JSON array. Until here everything is ok, but, when I want to show the values on the view I'm getting nothing. I did it like I did it previously and don't know why it's not working.

There is the controller:

```
assets.controller('DetallTipusCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams){
                $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/getDetails/'+$routeParams.param).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.atrb = data;
                });
                $scope.param = $routeParams.param;    
            });
```

And the view:

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="DetallTipusCtrl">
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th><a href="">Atribut</a></th>
                        <th><a href="">Mida</a></th>
                        <th><a href="">Tipus</a></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="atribut in atrb | orderBy:sortField:reverse">
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{{atribut.nomAtribut}}</td>
                        <td>{{atribut.midaAtribut}}</td>
                        <td>{{atribut.valor}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

The JSON array is well constructed but I can't see nothing and I don't know why, if anyone can help.. Thanks!

Edit:
The JSON:

```
{"nomAtribut":"fgdsgsfd","midaAtribut":"16","valor":"String","tipus_actius_idtipus_actius":"26","nom":"yiuhdfiau837629875wf"}
```

Solved:

The JSON array was a JSON object, thats how I iterate over and show properties:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in atrb">
    <td>{{value.propertie}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: can we see the json?

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi I just added

Comment: there is no sortfield property in your json

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi I removed the sortfield and still don't work

Comment: do your response is successful?

Comment: @hadiJZ said check your service first if its working, log it in console

Comment: @hadiJZ the web service is working

Comment: @proktovief is console showing any errors? (Just covering all the bases)

Comment: @proktovief did you check the console for any js errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response is not an array, its an object. You can iterate over object properties like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in atrb">
    <td>{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you need to show properties conditionally you can check the key.

Comment: With your solution I see the JSON array into the table cell

Comment: Yes it's working fine now I missed the properties on the view. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in your success function

```
    $http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/getDetails/'+$routeParams.param).success(function(data) {

   $scope.$evalAsync(function(){$scope.atrb = data;});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

make `$http` call like :

```
$http.get('http://10.0.203.73/WS/ws.php/tipusactius/getDetails/'+$routeParams.param)
.then(function(response) {$scope.atrb = response.data;});
```

Answer (score 0):

your response is not an array

```
        <td>{{atrb.nomAtribut}}</td>
         <td>{{atrb.midaAtribut}}</td>
         <td>{{atrb.valor}}</td>
```

to display use above code